# How to merge data from a query with two separate collections?

Tags: powerapps

I've got two galleries on a screen and I'm trying to merge the data from a query (datSavedWipDetails) into the collection data displayed in those two galleries.    I'm iterating over the items in datSavedWipDetails and trying to update the proper item in the designated section's collection but I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Patch seems to buggy to me. I've had problems with it where sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. I've found UpdateIf to be more reliable in most cases.

```
/* Iterate over datSavedWipDetails and incorporate with top & bottom galleries  */
If(CountRows(datSavedWipDetails) <> 0, 

  ForAll(datSavedWipDetails, 
    UpdateIf(Filter(colItemsInTopDisplay, wipProductCodeID = ThisRecord.ProductCodeID), wipDisplaySection = "Top",{ItemSCQty: wipItemSCQty });
    UpdateIf(Filter(colItemsInBottomDisplay, wipProductCodeID = ThisRecord.ProductCodeID), wipDisplaySection = "Bottom" ,{SCQty: wipItemSCQty })
  );
  /* End ForAll */ 
 , false);
/* End If */
```

This is updating the collections but the updates are not being reflected in the display. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I needed to remove the filter and use that filtering condition in the UpdateIf statement like so...

```
  ForAll(datSavedWipDetails, 
    UpdateIf(colChgReqSCReview, wipDisplaySection = "Top" && wipProductCodeID = ProductCodeID, {ItemSCQty: wipItemSCQty });
    UpdateIf(colSCSkusForNewOrder, wipDisplaySection = "Bottom" && wipProductCodeID = ProductCodeID, {SCQty: wipItemSCQty });
  );
```